# on the password prompt, the shell automatically adds a return after entering a character and displays authentication failed

Tags: command-line, bash, ubuntu-16.04, xterm

logging in to an `ubuntu 16.04` server via `ssh`. This has never happened before. The other user I asked seems unaffected by this. What could have happened? Also, when I try to enter my git credentials and press `return`, the shell replaces it with `^M`, `backspace` with a `^?`. When I open a tmux session, things work as they should.